# Assigning null/Nullable to DateTime in Ternary Operation

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datetime, nullable

I have a statement like

```
DateTime ? dt = (string1 == string2) ? null; (DateTime)(txtbox.Text);
```

which I cannot compile. Reason is : `null` cannot be assigned to `DateTime`.

So, I have to declare a `Nullable<DateTime> nullable` variable and replace `null` with `nullable`.

I do not want to use `if`-statement and I want to do this in one line.

Also, Can I use operator `??` here.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
DateTime? dt = (string1 == string2) ? (DateTime?)null
                                    : DateTime.Parse(txtbox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that:

```
DateTime ? dt = (string1 == string2) ? new Nullable <DateTime>(): (DateTime)(txtbox.Text);
```

Comment: You can't directly cast a `string` to a `DateTime`. You'll need to use the `Parse` method instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx