# SqlDataReader no data, but HasRow is true

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader, no-data

I read data from SQL database by **ExecuteReader().**
There are no data fulfill conditions, but **HasRow** returns true. When I try to read data from reader I got exception:
*'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'*

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();     
if (reader.HasRows)
            try
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                        string aa = reader.GetFieldType(0).Name; // aa returns 'DateTime'
                        dateStart.MinDate = reader.GetDateTime(0); //exception on this line
                        dateEnd.MinDate = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                        dateStart.Value = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
               reader.Close();
            }
```

Thanks in advance
Usjwo

Comment: Have you checked the value with `if (reader.IsDBNull(0))` or ternary operator? You can't use `GetDateTime` if the corresponding field value is null.

Comment: This could help you ----> [Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581305/data-is-null-this-method-or-property-cannot-be-called-on-null-values-using-com)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data inside zero index of `SqlDataReader` contains `DBNull`, you can't use `GetDateTime` method directly from it since `DBNull.Value` can't be directly cast to `DateTime`. You can check it using [`IsDBNull`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581305/data-is-null-this-method-or-property-cannot-be-called-on-null-values-using-com) with ternary operator & a `Nullable<DateTime>` variable to store `GetDateTime` result before assigning to other properties (see also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215199/assigning-null-nullable-to-datetime-in-ternary-operation)):

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DateTime? minDate = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? (DateTime?)null : reader.GetDateTime(0);
                if (minDate != null)
                {
                    dateStart.MinDate = minDate.Value;
                    dateEnd.MinDate = minDate.Value;
                    dateStart.Value = minDate.Value;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```